# MongoDB fuzzy match from request parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query users with regex and having some issues. For my route I have parameter in `req.query.search` which is a string.

I googled around and found that I can use `/ /` as a regex for fuzzy matching.

The code below doesn't work and returns no results.

```
User.find({firstName: /req.query.search/} , function (err, users) {
    if (err)
      return res.send(err);

    return res.status(200).send(users);
  });
};
```

The following code works as behaves and returns the expected result.

```
User.find({firstName: /Me/} , function (err, users) {
    if (err)
      return res.send(err);

    return res.status(200).send(users);
  });
};
```

How can I use the value from the query in the `find()`?

Comment: When Using regular expression literal, the pattern that will be matched is what is there in between //. In the examples given, it will be 'Me' and 'req.query.search' .  When you have variable pattern, use `new RegExp(req.query.search)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think this may be possible using something like below,

```
var match = new RegExp(req.query.search);
User.find({firstName: match} , function (err, users) {
    if (err){
        return res.send(err);
    }
    return res.status(200).send(users);
});
```

Comment: Nice it works! Is it possible to get it to ignore case?

Comment: what you mean by ignore case?